# isc-dhcp-server not replying to relayed requests

Tags: isc-dhcp

DHCP request is being relayed from a server in a different subnet to the ISC-DHCP box.
ISC-DHCP is not responding

dhcpd.conf is like this:

```
subnet 10.0.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.254 {} 

host test {
  hardware ethernet 32:b8:ee:57:1e:e0;
  fixed-address 192.168.200.222;
  option routers 192.168.200.1;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}
```

DHCP request is arriving at this server from 10.0.1.11
but no response.  I see this in the logs:

```
DHCPDISCOVER from 32:b8:ee:57:1e:e0 via 10.0.1.11: network 10.0.1.10/31: no free leases
```

Any thoughts?  There is nothing in the leases file for any of these subnets

Comment: So we're understanding, you're expecting host with MAC address `32:b8:ee:57:1e:e0` to be assigned the only available IP address in that subnet, 10.01.11, even though something is already using that address and your DHCP server is communicating with it?

Comment: no, host with mac `32:b8:ee:57:1e:e0` should be assigned 192.168.200.222.

10.0.1.10/31 just needs to exist in the config file as that is the subnet DHCP is being relayed from